# Having issues with this simple program

Tags: c, macos, if-statement, integer, conditional-statements

The program is just simply supposed to calculate the users age by subtracting their dob from the current year. When I run the program it compiles successfully but I get a long number such as -215863352. The if and else conditions are added just to test them out, I was writing various programs using them to make sure I understand the syntax in c. I figure I'm missing something simple but can't figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int year;
    int cyear;
    int age = cyear - year;

    printf("Please enter the year you were born: \n");
    scanf("%i", &year);
    printf("Now enter the current year: \n");
    scanf("%i", &cyear);

    if (1+1 == 2){
        printf("You must be %i", age);
    }
    else {
        printf("Cannot compute age, GOODBYE:\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1: instructions are executed sequencially, a program is not an Excel Sheet, you need to put `int age = cyear - year;` __after__ the scanfs. 2: `1 + 1 == 2` is always true, therefore the `if` is pointless here.

Comment: Initialize age as an int, then put `age = cyear - year` after the scanf.

Comment: C source is executed sequentially from top to bottom. Your beginner-level C book ought to be explaining this.

Comment: any reasonably decent compiler should report warnings pointing to the cause: "main.c(6) : warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'cyear', 'year' used. hence, initialize those variables with default values before using them in a computation.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the age before the input is taken from the user. So the `age` variable is storing a garbage value.

Solution:

Position the calculation of age after taking the input from user that is after taking input of `cyear` using scanf. The correct code is given below
#include <stdio.h>

```
int main()
{
    int year;
    int cyear;
    int age =0;     //initialise with 0

    printf("Please enter the year you were born: \n");
    scanf("%i", &year);
    printf("Now enter the current year: \n");
    scanf("%i", &cyear);
    
    age = cyear - year;     //note the change here

    if (1+1 == 2){
        printf("You must be %i", age);
    }
    else {
        printf("Cannot compute age, GOODBYE:\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
enter code here
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main()
   {
  long long int year;
  printf("Please enter the year you were born: \n");
scanf("%lld",&year);
long long int cyear;
  printf("Now enter the current year: \n");
scanf("%lld",&cyear);

long long  int age = cyear-year;

if (1){
    printf("You must be %lld", age);
}
else {  printf("Now enter the current year: \n");
scanf("%lld",&cyear);

    printf("Cannot compute age, GOODBYE:\n");
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: it seems that the problem appeared beacuse initialization.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please include an explanation of your answer, not just code. :)

Comment: If have a calculation (for example age=cyear_year) before initialization it will lead to wrong answer because you don’t know the present mount  of your variable .and it gets some value from memory.